# Dynamic DB storage based on unknown result from source

Tags: sql, mysql, dynamic

I have a source of data that I get from a webService. I can never know when it'll change and I need to store it in a DB as soon as I get it. What is the best way to make the storage solution adapt to what I put there. I am using mySQL. Would serialization be the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the context in a column using the TEXT data type, and consider MEDIUMTEXT or LONGTEXT if the content is over 4000 characters.  [MySQL 5.1 has XML functionality to get values out of the XML payload](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-5.1-xml.html)...

Ideally, I'd consume the webservice and populate tables appropriately.

Comment: In your ideal situation, how would you counter for the fact that it might change without notice? I am bound to use it =/

Comment: @Phil: Change without notice?  Then the best you can do is store as text/string...  I wonder how one would expect to consistently get anything of value from such a situation, though.

Comment: It's my situation though.. all I can do is look cheerful and try to make the best of it hehe :)